# How to create a Setup file for window application?

Tags: installation, setup-project

I'm studying how to create a C# Application. I done all step and build the release of application. I have created "Setup Project" in VS2019 and built it already. After build, I found 2 files with different extensions : "Setup.exe" and "Setup.msi" [image: This is my release folder after build]

I copy a single file into my teacher machine and it didn't work but if copy both files, it work well. I have tried use **InstallShield** with Advanced UI Project and add 2 files, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me how to merge these files or how to create a single file can work well same as these files?

Comment: Did you try just right-clicking the Setup.msi and choose "Install" from the context menu?

Comment: @Filburt Yes, I have tried it already, but it will error because miss prerequisites.

Comment: You can configure your Setup Project to check and automatically (download) and install any prerequisites. See the documentation on the [Prerequisites dialog box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/prerequisites-dialog-box?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @Filburt I have checked. But it create another setup file which is "Setup.exe".

Comment: Anybody have an answer ? Please help me.